# primefaces jsf p:ajax event keyup ignore arrow keys

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, keyup

I have a inputText field that has a validate button next to it.  When you click the validate button it does some backend validation and a green check mark appears next to the button.  I want that green check mark to disappear when the value changes, and right away not when losing focus because there is a test button on the page that i also disable/enable when valid. so event="blur" or even="change" won't work cause they can click the button when the input text field has changed.  I used keyup and that works great, but arrow keys and tab etc... trigger the event and I dont want them to.

```
<h:inputText id="baseURL" style="width:425px;" value="#{View.baseURL}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="validIcon :addEditCatalogForm:testUrlButton" listener="#{View.resetValidation()}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I see JQuery options for this, but I need one that works with the jsf and primefaces tags.

Comment: Can't you save the validated value and compare that against the value when the `listener` is called? JSF should update it before the listener gets called.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I don't want the items on the page to get updated on arrow and tab clicks.  Is there a way in the listener method to prevent the update?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen here : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24788

The solution would be close to :

```
<h:inputText id="baseURL" style="width:425px;" value="#{View.baseURL}" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode != ####_YOUR_KEYS_####) return false;">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this keyCode" update="validIcon :addEditCatalogForm:testUrlButton" listener="#{View.resetValidation()}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: That will work, but I instead did this via backend, so the input text element is not cluttered.  I posted my answer below, but thanks for getting me on track to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

So using Thrax's answer I did it using the back end.  I think this solution is messy, and I hope there is a cleaner way to do this, so If anyone else has a better solution please let me know.

Here is the code:

```
  <h:inputText id="baseURL" style="width:425px;" value="#{bean.valueYouAreChanging}" onkeyup="document.getElementById('#{keyCode.clientId}').value=event.keyCode">
        <p:ajax event="keyup" process="@this keyCode" update="validIcon :form:testUrlButtonPost" listener="#{bean.resetValidation}"/>
  </h:inputText>
  <h:inputHidden id="keyCode" binding="#{keyCode}" value="#{bean.keyCode}" />
```

Here is the bean code.  I don't want a lot of keys to trigger the change such as arrow keys, tab, enter, home, end, etc...

```
public void resetValidation() {

    String[] invalidKeys = {"9","13","16","17","18","19","20","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","45","224"};
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String key : invalidKeys) {
        keys.add(key);
    }
    if(!keys.contains(keyCode)) {
        validBaseURL = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution by just returning your arrays of invalid keys as a JS array string:

```
public String getInvalidKeysJSArray() {
    return "[9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 224]";
}
```

Then in your input component, the `onkeyup` parameter would look like

```
onkeyup="return '#{keyUtilsController.invalidKeysJSArray}'.indexOf(event.keyCode) &lt; 0;"
```

Please note that IE `Array` prototype might not contain the `indeoxOf` function.